# How to align a paragraph to the right in c++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, text

For example this text will become:

```
lui Andino ii place
mult informatica si doreste
sa mearga la olimpiada
pentru a-si dovedi calitatile de mare informatician
```

```
                                lui Andino ii place
                        mult informatica si doreste
                             sa mearga la olimpiada
pentru a-si dovedi calitatile de mare informatician
```

My idea is to find the longest size of a text line(named maxx in my code) and add to the other lines "maxx - size of the text line" spaces.

for example:

```
I eat.
I eat everyday at 5 pm in the morning.
```

I will place in the front "the size of second line of text minus the first line of text" spaces.

This is what I ve done until now.

```
        cin >> t ///t is the number of line of text
        int maxx = 0, t1 = t, k = 0;
        vector<string> str;
        while(t--)
        {
            string s;
            getline(cin, s);
            str.push_back(s);


            if (s.size() > maxx)
                maxx = s.size();
        }
        for (int j = 0 ; j < t1; j++)
        {
            if (str[i].length() < maxx)
            {
                str[i].insert(0, ' ', maxx - str[i].length());
            }
            cout << str[i] << "\n";
        }
```

It works all fine, unless some lines of my output are filled with unknown caracter.

This is what the program compiles:

```
                                                lui Andino ii place
mult informatica si doreste
sa mearga la olimpiada
pentru a-si dovedi calitatile de mare informatician
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You don't have to modify the strings, all you have to do is use the right [I/O manipulator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited my answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there are like 30  I/O manipulator

Comment: There's one that is commonly used to *set field width*, and there's two to set *left* or *right* justification. Just look through the list and you should be able to figure them out.

Comment: @MogovanJonathan have a look at the examples here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left

Comment: Look this exemple, it is all that you need, nothing more: [Right alignement cout](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4f2f6c4de4fd58b)

Comment: and what is wrong with my program?

Comment: the right alignement works fine!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend that you use the [range-base `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over your vector.

Secondly, all you need to output right-aligned is to [set the field width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to the size of the longest string, and make all output [right justified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left):

```
for (auto const& s : str)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(maxx) << std::right << s << '\n';
}
```

Note that this doesn't require you to pad each string, in fact it requires you not to do it.